# determining odd and even functions

Tags: functions

> Assume $p$ is an even function and $q$ is an odd function, given $p,q$ lies on the entire real line, determine if $p \circ q$ is an even or odd function

Fundamentally,

Even function: $f(x) = f(-x)$

Odd function: $f(x) = -f(x) $

can I say that $p\circ q$ is an odd function because:

$ (p \circ q)(x) = p(q(-x)) = p(-q(x)) = -(p\circ q)(x) $ ?

Comment: Because $p$ is even, the last term should be $pq(x)$.  So, the composition is even.

Comment: You can type the composition symbol by writing \circ.

Comment: Use $p\circ q$ for composition (circ), and not $poq$.

Comment: @Doug since $q$ is an odd function, $q(-x) = -q(x)$, if I multiply 2 functions together and if one function has a negative sign, shouldn't it be $-pq(x)$ as the final? so $pq(x) = -pq(x)$ which is an odd function, why is it an even function ?

Comment: Composition is not the same as multiplying.  Note the difference between $(p(q(x))$ and $pq(x)$.

Comment: $\require{cancel}$$(p\circ q)(\cancel x\color{green}{-x})=p(q(-x))=p(-q(x))\color{green}{=p(q(x))}=\color{red}{\cancel -}(p\circ q)(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both compositions are even:
$$p(q(-x)) = p(-q(x)) = p(q(x)),\quad \text{and}\quad  q(p(-x)) = q(p(x)).$$